# Making ChartJs kindof look like Morris.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

So I have been given a small task by one of the graphic designers I work with, whereby we need to have a graph similar to the doughnut graph, that can be seen on the `morris.js` homepage in the sense the `tooltip` is in the center of the doughnut, but we are using `chartjs` to get the nice loading animation.

After some investigation, to try and get `Morris.js` to do the animation, this was found to be extremely difficult, so I opted to go for making `ChartJs` appear more like `morris.js`.

To add to the complexity (ever so slightly) we are using angular for alot of our logic, and to implement numerous features, so we have gone with [angular-chartjs](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js/tree/chartjs-2.0) which is suiting our purposes quite nicely.

Now to the nitty gritty.

So far I've gotten quite close I think to replicating the general idea that Morris JS has done. I tried to do my code in a `jsfiddle` but for some reason I can't get the `angular-chart.js` to work.

Basically the issue I am having is in the afterLabel function, I'm a little stumped as to how to get it to center, so both the main label and the afterLabel both are centered in the doughnut.

I won't say the code I did is particularly pleasant, but it seems to so far be working, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

I should also note, the code does work using standard chartjs, and you can find the fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/maraket/5qpsztrm/ which seems to work just fine except for the centering.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      bodyColor: "#000",
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
      custom: function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.bodyFontSize = this._chartInstance.innerRadius / 4;
        var txt = [
          (tooltip.beforeTitle || []).join('\n'), (tooltip.title || []).join('\n'), (tooltip.afterTitle || []).join('\n'), (tooltip.beforeBody || []).join('\n'), (tooltip.body || []).join('\n'), (tooltip.afterBody || []).join('\n'), (tooltip.beforeFooter || [])
          .join('\n'), (tooltip.footer || []).join('\n'), (tooltip.afterFooter || []).join('\n')
        ];
        txt = txt.join("\n");
        tooltip.y = ((this._chartInstance.chartArea.bottom - this._chartInstance.chartArea.top) / 2) + this._chartInstance.chartArea.top - tooltip.bodyFontSize;
        tooltip.x = (this._chart.width / 2) - (this._chart.ctx.measureText(txt).width / 1.5);
      },
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
        },
        afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```